# How to prevent a page from reloading On click a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Please find the code snippet below,

```js
$(function(){
    $('.img_reset_confirm').on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
     <form method="post" action="{{ url }}" class="form_sec">
                    <div>
                        <p class="txt1">Are you sure?</p>
                        <p class="txt2">
                            <input type="submit" class="txt_btn6 top " value="OK" />
                            <a href="#" class="close txt_btn6 plug_tmp_btn image_clear img_reset_confirm">close</a>
                        </p>
                        <p class="close">
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Above div block is a modal popup, where if I click OK, modal close & page shouldn't get reloaded. It should stay in that same place. I've tried so many ways but I failed. Help me to resolve the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: change order in your click event listener. You are returning without envoking `preventDefault()`

Comment: Because your `ok` has `type="submit"` your form submits when  you click on it and page refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the event handler to the form, not the image.

```
$('.form_sec').on('submit', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Why is the `return true` used at all?

Comment: it shouldn't be used

Comment: If I do like the above, the modal closes, the page reloads & control goes to the top of the screen. But I don't want the page to get reloaded & control should be in the same place where I left.

Comment: @Naveen remove the function

Comment: @JuniusL. I've removed the function but still the page is reloading